# Fopen(/path/) failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

How to fix failed to open stream: is a directory, I'm using `ubuntu 16.04` and `PHP CodeIgniter` framework.

Code

```
 public function downloadFiles()
 {
      $estructure = "/home/administrator/Downloads/pdfs_new12/";
      $data =  $this->Mdi_download_invoices->download_pdf_files(12);    
        foreach ($data as $d)
        {
             $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
             $html = $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$data,true);
             $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
             $mpdf->Output($estructure.$d->invoice_id);
        }
  }
```

I'm trying to generate multiple PDF files, it generates all files in specified directory but at end of the process it will shows a warning called

> "Fopen(/path/)failed to open stream: Is a directory"

And also throws a message called Unable to create output `file /path/`

Comment: `$data['d'] = $data;` Why this line?

Comment: by mistake, its removed

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$mpdf->Output('Your-Location' . 'Your-File-Name.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```

Comment: Please avoid "try this: [some code]" suggestions without explaning what you suggest and how it is supposed to help. Although this may help, such answers do not comply SO quality standarts (those who see the answer, each should try blindly to check if this works). Best regards

Comment: Ok, I will try to follow your advice from next time.

Comment: Why not this time? :) You can always edit your answer using the "edit" button